# Algorithm - How to delete duplicate elements in a Haskell list

Tags: haskell

I'm having a problem creating an function similar to the nub function.

I need this func to remove duplicated elements form a list. 
An element is duplicated when 2 elements have the same email, and it should keep the newer one (is closer to the end of the list).

```
type Regist = [name,email,,...,date]
type ListRe = [Regist]

rmDup ListRe -> ListRe
rmDup [] = []
rmDup [a] = [a]
rmDup (h:t) | isDup h (head t) = rmDup t
            | otherwise = h : rmDup t

isDup :: Regist -> Regist -> Bool
isDup (a:b:c:xs) (d:e:f:ts) = b==e
```

The problem is that the function doesn't delete duplicated elements unless they are together in the list.

Comment: Why is this tagged `[generic-algorithm]`?

Comment: Isn't it just frmDup = rmDup . sortBy (on compare (!!1)) ? Or do you need to retain the original order (minus all duplicates)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly doctored version of your original code to make it run:

```
type Regist = [String]
type ListRe = [Regist]

rmDup :: ListRe -> ListRe
rmDup [] = []
rmDup (x:xs) = x : rmDup (filter (\y -> not(x == y)) xs)
```

Result:

```
*Main> rmDup [["a", "b"], ["a", "d"], ["a", "b"]]
[["a","b"],["a","d"]]
```

Answer (score 12):

Just use `nubBy`, and specify an equality function that compares things the way you want.

And I guess reverse the list a couple of times if you want to keep the last element instead of the first.

Comment: Assuming `RegList` is actually `[String]`, the equality function would be as simple as `import Data.Function (on); (==) \`on\` (!! 1)`.

Answer (score 4):

Anon is correct: `nubBy` is the function you are looking for, and can be found in Data.List.

That said, you want a function `rem` which accepts a list `xs` and a function `f :: a -> a -> Bool` (on which elements are compared for removal from `xs`). Since the definition is recursive, you need a base case and a recursive case.

In the base case `xs = []` and `rem f xs = []`, since the result of removing all duplicate elements from `[]` is `[]`:

```
rem :: Eq a => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
rem f [] = []
```

In the recursive case, `xs = (a:as)`. Let `as'` be the list obtained by removing all elements `a'` such that `f a a' = True` from the list `as`. This is simply the function `filter (\a' -> not $ f a a')` applied to the list `as`. Them `rem f (a:as)` is the result of recursively calling `rem f` on `as'`, that is, `a : rem f as'`:

```
rem f (a:as) = a : rem f $ filter (\a' -> not $ f a a') as
```

Replace `f` be a function comparing your list elements for the appropriate equality (e-mail addresses).

Comment: `rem` is not a good choice of name; there is already a `rem` (remainder) function in the Prelude.

Comment: I could have used `f` or `asdf` and the idea would have been the same. He wanted an algorithm for "nubbing" a list by a function, which is what, hopefully, I gave.

Answer (score 3):

While `nubBy` with two `reverse`'s is probably the best among simple solutions (and probably exactly what Justin needs for his task), one should not forget that it isn't the ideal solution in terms of efficiency - after all `nubBy` is O(n^2) (in the "worst case" - when there are no duplicates). Two `reverse`'s will also take their toll (in the form of memory allocation).
For more efficient implementation `Data.Map` (O(logN) on inserts) can be used as an intermediate "latest non duplicating element" holder (Set.insert replaces older element with newer if there is a collision):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function
import qualified Data.Set as S

newtype Regis i e = Regis { toTuple :: (i,[e]) }

selector (Regis (_,(_:a:_))) = a 

instance Eq e => Eq (Regis i e) where
    (==) = (==) `on` selector

instance Ord e => Ord (Regis i e) where
    compare = compare `on` selector

rmSet xs = map snd . sortBy (compare `on` fst) . map toTuple . S.toList $ set
    where
      set = foldl' (flip (S.insert . Regis)) S.empty (zip [1..] xs)
```

While `nubBy` implementation is definitely much simpler:

```
rmNub xs = reverse . nubBy ((==) `on` (!!1)) . reverse $ xs
```

on 10M elements list (with lots of duplication - `nub` should play nice here) there is 3 times difference in terms of running time and 700 times difference in memory usage. Compiled with GHC with -O2 :

```
input = take 10000000 $ map (take 10) $ permutations [1..]

test1 = rmNub input
test2 = rmSet input
```

Not sure about the nature of the author's data though (the real data might change the picture).

Comment: `foldl' (flip (S.insert . Regis)) S.empty (zip [1..] xs)` can be written as `S.fromList $ zipWith Regis [1..] xs`

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming you want to figure out an answer, not just call a library function that does this job for you.)

You get what you ask for.  What if `h` is not equal to `head t` but is instead equal to the 3rd element of `t`?  You need to write an algorithm that compares `h` with *every* element of `t`, not just the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Why not putting everything in a Map from email to Regist (of course respecting your "keep the newest" rule), and then transform the values of the map back in the list? That's the most efficient way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Alexei Polkhanov's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4496174/1048722) answer and came to the following, so you can remove duplicates from lists with a type that extends Eq class.

```
removeDuplicates :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
removeDuplicates [] = []
removeDuplicates (x:xs) = x : removeDuplicates (filter (\y -> not (x == y)) xs)
```

Examples:

```
*Verdieping> removeDuplicates [[1],[2],[1],[1,2],[1,2]]
[[1],[2],[1,2]]

*Verdieping> removeDuplicates [["a","b"],["a"],["a","b"],["c"],["c"]]
[["a","b"],["a"],["c"]]
```