# basic haskell: converting [[int]] to [int]

Tags: haskell

Is there any easy way to change a [[int]] to [int] or to compare them in this form to find out if there are missing elements.

For example

```
  set1=   [[1,2,3]] 
  set2= [2,3,]
```

to return [1]. I tried this:

```
return s1 s2= [x|x<-s1,y<-s2, x/=y]
```

**Follow up Question:**
how can I prevent duplicates being returned
eg if

```
set1 = [[1,1,1,2,3]
```

how can I get the return function to give me only [1]

Comment: Is this really what you want? "how can I get the return function to give me only [1]" and not [1,2,3]

Comment: These are really a few separate questions here.  I'm not sure what's being asked?  How to remove duplicates?  How to find the difference between two lists?  How to convert a list of lists into an int?

Comment: btw you can't end list declaration with a coma as in set2 above

Comment: @AaronMcDaid The first question has my answer has a good one, I think. John added a new one, called followup question but yes basically it should be two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be approximately three distinct questions here.

*First question*, how to convert a list of list of ints into a list?

```
concat [[1,1,2],[2,1,3]] == [1,1,2,2,1,3]
```

*Second question*, how to remove duplicates from a list?  You can use [nub](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3anub) for that (remember to `import Data.List`):

```
nub [1,2,1,3] == [1,2,3]
```

Perhaps you simply want to delete *consecutive* duplicates?  For example, if you know you've already sorted the list:

```
map head (group [1,1,1,2,3]) == [1,2,3]
```

In that, `group` will group them into lists of consecutive duplicates, then `head` is used to return only the first of each group of duplicates.

*Third question*, how to find the items in list1 that are *not* in list2:

[`list1 \\ list2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3a-92--92-)

Be careful though, that `\\` mightn't operate as expected if the lists aren't in order and if either list includes dupes.  Read it carefully if you want to understand it's behaviour in those cases.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have included these three answers!  The three questions should perhaps be separate questions on SO.

Comment: Yes it is like he is adding more and more questions :D

Answer (score 3):

If you have [[1,2,3]] you can just use `concat`

```
Prelude> x
[[1,2,3]]
Prelude> concat x
[1,2,3]
Prelude>
```

For the second part, I invite you to read this [Algorithm - How to delete duplicate elements in a Haskell list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495256/algorithm-how-to-delete-duplicate-elements-in-a-haskell-list)

There is a straight forward implementation there.

Comment: Why not just ``head``?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks but is there anyway I can prevent duplicates in my code being returned? For example if there were two ones in set1 can I prevent two 1's being returned?

Comment: @Bogdan head would work in this case but if set1 was [2,3,1] or [2,1,3] it would not.

Comment: Accept the answer or modify your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat` to convert from `[[a]]` to `[a]`, and `nub` (from `Data.List`) to remove duplicate elements from a list.

Demonstration in ghci:

```
>  import Data.List (nub)  
>  let set1 = [[1,2,3]]  
>  let set2 = [2,3]  
>  concat set1 == set2  
False  
>  let set1 = [[1,1,1,2,3]]  
>  nub (concat set1)  
[1,2,3]
```